# Could not load the Tomcat server configuration The servers project is closed

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

When trying to add the project to work with my tomcat server by right clicking on Tomcat server > add& remove > adding the project to work with the server I get the error "Could not load the Tomcat server configuration, The servers project is closed.

usually this happens when you open a new Dynamic web project & you don't have a servers folder coming from Tomcat or when the servers folder is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

right click File > New > Server> *select the installed Tomcat version* > click on your project > add > finish.

## 2  if you already have a Tomcat server up:

simply make sure the serves folder is not closed (gray), if it is right click on the servers folder & open project, then simply right click on your Tomcat server on the bottom, add & remove, add you project & your'e done!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the "Close unrelated projects" button is clicked. The most straightforward solution to this issue:

1. Go to the bottom of the Project Explorer tab and there will be a project named "Servers". If it's closed, the icon will have a different color than the projects that are open.
2. Double-clicking "Servers" will open the project and solve this issue. That's what worked for me though.